# Increasing hover tolerance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to increase the hover tolerance, to improve accidental hover while traversing through a menu.

Right now using a timeout when hovering from one menu item to other.

Wanted to know if there are any better way of solving this?

Tried using pseudo element but not very helpful, because when I am hover over that, the menu will not close but ideally when hover for longer time it should close the menu.
Any suggestions would be helpful and what can be issues with timeout  solution ?

Also tried increasing hover area, not solving the problem completely

And what are the cons of using timeout?

Comment: What do you want it to do that your current timeout based approach doesn't? It sounds like you already have what you want.

Comment: From what I read, I know that windows do not close menus, if the mouse direction & velocity (vector) intersects with any other open menus. There was a push to have this in the Angular Material menu, but in the end, it was deemed too hard to implement...

Comment: You are asking us to improve on code, but you do not show any code. This is like asking "My car isn't driving so well, if I tell you that it is blue, can you then fix it?" We need to see the engine, the clutch, the brakes etc, not a description of the exterior. In other words: please add some code.

Comment: @DBS the timeout solution is solving the problem completely but was trying to understand if there are any other solutions which I can check other than timeout.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.